# How do i use the experimental future Waveform visualizer

Tags: just-audio

I'm trying to use the audio visualizer, but getting startVisualizer function is not defined.
please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about the experimental visualizer on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/97#issuecomment-856720949):

> Clone this repo and checkout the visualizer branch. Inside, the example/ directory has been modified to demonstrate how to use the API. There are also some comments above on things to be tested on iOS - though Android should be reliable. I plan to rewrite the iOS implementation on top of AudioKit.

This is how to do the above instructions from the command-line:

```
git clone git@github.com:ryanheise/just_audio.git
cd just_audio
git checkout visualizer
cd just_audio/example
flutter pub get
flutter run
```